# Google Sheets: How can I extract text from a cell based on other text within the same cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Disclaimer: I am not a coder but a simple lowly project coordinator needing help with Google Sheets :D

I have the following text inside cell A1

```
[0] (SCL) Mary, Martha
[0] (SCC) 
[3] (MDL) John, Joe, Jerry
```

I would like to extract from A1 and the results in B1 should be

```
Mary, Martha
```

While cell C1 will result in

and finally for D1

```
John, Joe, Jerry
```

Essentially I want the cells to extract the names from A1 based on their 'code'; **(SCL), (SCC), and (MDL)** So B1 will contain names only with the code (SCL), C1 for names with the code (SCC), and D1 for names with the code (MDL) - and I wish to disregard the rest of the contents. I hope that made sense. Any help is appreciated. I struggle with regex stuff :(

I'll make do with a formula to extract just names from one of the codes btw! Thanks!

Comment: Is that correct...? You want cell C1 to be empty?

Comment: @Adriano Yep! That's because there are no names attached to the code (SCC) in cell A1 :)

Comment: I used a cumbersome workaround for now
`=split(A1, "()[]", true)`
then index, match the results like so
`=index(result range,1,match("MDL", result range, 0)+1`

Comment: Good. Add that to the question. I bet that's the missing bit that is getting your question voted down.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(split(A1, char(10)), "^.+\)\s?(.*)$", "$1" ))
```

[image]

Comment: What does "$1" mean here?

Comment: It refers to the first capturing group of the regex. See: https://regex101.com/r/NXQ4mX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (though your one example is very specific, causing me to wonder if every such cell will follow exactly this layout):

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\)([^\[]*)[^\)]+\)([^\[]*)[^\)]+\)(.+)$")))`

Looks confusing, I'm sure. It's important to understand that many of the characters in the cell itself have meaning to REGEX, so they need to be "escaped" with the backslash (which means they will be treated as literal characters when preceded by that backslash). So wherever you see a backslash, the next character is one from your actual string.

Here's what the formula means in plain English: "Find the first closing parenthesis. Then capture as many characters as possible that are not an opening square bracket and return them. Ignore everything up to the next closing parenthesis and then again capture as many characters as possible that are not an opening square bracket and return them. Once again, ignore everything up the next closing parenthesis and return everything that's left to the end of the string."